# In tabulator, what setting will allow for table to expand so that all contents are visible?

Tags: tabulator

When using `fitColumns` setting of tabulator, if the table is wider than the containing div, the columns shrink so they the table fits in the div. It appears one can use `widthShrink: 0` to prevent column shrinking (I have not tried this yet). Is it possible to specify `widthShrink` for all columns? I am creating the table from an existing table, and hence do not specify columns and data manually.

Also, is it possible to prevent the scrollbar on the table div when the table gets wider than the containing div. I would prefer that the user scroll the entire page to see the table (instead of just the table div).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong layout mode if you want the columns to overflow the table, ***fitColumns*** is specifically designed to fit the columns to the table. the ***fitData*** layout mode will allow the columns to overflow the table naturally. You can set `widthShrink: 0` on all the columns, but at that point you are essentially disabling the layout mode anyway.

There is no built in feature for allowing external scrolling of the table. The table is based in a `div` and so will take up 100% the width of its parent element.

It will then either handle scrolling inside the table or resize the columns to fit depending on how your table is configured

You could make some CSS tweaks to allow this form of display but it may cause the table to malfunction under certain circumstance, depending on your configuration.

You would need to include the following CSS after the tabulator style sheet has been included:

```
.tabulator, .tabulator-header, .tabulator-tableHolder{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

But essentially at that point you may be better off just using a standard HTML table as you seem to be disabling a lot of the features that you would use Tabulator for.